# Extracting a single-valued map from a multi-valued map $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm wanting to know if my instincts are right on this one. I have a multi-valued function $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$, i.e., maps each $s \in [0,1]$ to at least one, but *possibly more* (finitely many) values in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I know the following notion of "continuity" holds for this map. Consider *any* $t \in [0,1]$, and any $\zeta_t \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that $t$ is mapped to, and any $\epsilon >0$. Then, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|s-t|< \delta$, then there exists some $\zeta_s \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that $s$ is mapped to, with $|\zeta_t - \zeta_s| < \epsilon$.

The picture in my head vividly seems to tell me that I can then extract a single-valued continuous function $s \mapsto \zeta_s$ for $s \in [0,1]$ (where each $\zeta_s$ is one of the points that the multi-valued function maps $s$ to).

Is this right?

Comment: But then the "extracted" 1-1 map won't be defined in the whole $\;[0,1]\;$ but in some subset of it. Is this what you want?

Comment: I don’t see why I can’t get a function on all of [0,1]?

Comment: Because you must take out all the points with the same image but one!

Comment: I’m really sorry, I don’t quite understand why?

Comment: Oh, I don’t need it to be 1-1! Just continuous.

Comment: But even in your post's title you say "a single valued map"...and don't even mention continuity!

Comment: Excuse me, but a single valued function is simply a function. A multi valued “function” is not a function in its usual sense: a single point in the domain can be mapped to MANY values. There is nothing here to do with injectivity. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function

Answer (score 1):

No.  For instance, consider the multivalued function $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ whose graph is $$[0,1)\times\{0\}\cup(0,1]\times\{1\}.$$  This satisfies your condition: for any value of the function at a point $t$, you can find an open neighborhood of $t$ where it takes the same value.  But this multivalued function does not contain any continuous single-valued function defined on all of $[0,1]$.